# Do I set up as self employed for a one off job?

Tags: united-kingdom, self-employment

I am currently employed as a graphic designer but have been approached by a friend to create a website for them. Fee will be around £1000 but it's only going to happen once, guarantee it.  Therefore, do I need to set myself up as self employed for tax purposes? Or can I just declare it at the end of the tax year as a miscellaneous or irregular income?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are in the UK, as you quoted GBP (£).

You can check for yourself whether your work on the website can be classified as self-employment [at the HMRC website](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/check-employment-status-for-tax).

From what you described, no, you should not be self-employed for income tax purposes - since this is [not an ongoing endeavor](http://www.brighton-accountants.com/blog/tax-self-employment-still-employed/), you won't necessarily have to register a business. You will, however, be required to [fill out a “self-assessment.”](https://www.gov.uk/log-in-file-self-assessment-tax-return/register-if-youre-not-self-employed)

As stated [here](https://www.crunch.co.uk/blog/contractor-advice/2014/02/04/freelancing-side-tax-implications/), however, "It’s a legal requirement to register with the taxman as a new business as soon as your combined earnings (from your full-time employment and any other work) exceed your personal allowance." So there is some gray area here.

Your best bet is to [call HMRC directly](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-revenue-customs/contact/self-assessment). Apparently, you can ask them to [“amend your tax coding”](https://www.reddit.com/r/UKPersonalFinance/comments/2nh0aa/do_i_need_to_complete_a_self_assessment_for_a_one/?st=j69z0vk8&sh=ce53b40e) to account for the miscellaneous income.

There was [proposed legislation](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/income-tax-new-tax-allowance-for-property-and-trading-income/income-tax-new-tax-allowance-for-property-and-trading-income) to allow for up to £1000 exemption on side income. However, [as of April 2017](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/news/protect/2017/04/government-drops-1000-tax-breaks-for-online-sellers-and-room-renters-for-now), this bit of legislation was shelved, so don't count on it just yet.